# ASP.NET role management with SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, web-config, sql-server-2012

After many attempts to use roles management in an ASP.NET project, I am in need of help.

I have a local SQL Server set up, and here are some parts of my `web.config` file...

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebSite2-20130703132914;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebSite2-20130703132914.mdf"/>
   <add name="SqlRoleManagerConnection" 
        connectionString="Data Source=my-pc;&#xA;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
</connectionStrings>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"   
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="SqlRoleManager" 
         connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection" applicationName="/" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The application is called WebSite.

`aspnetdb` is already set up on the local database and is ready to manage roles...

When I go to the ASP.NET configuration option in visual studio 2012 express, under security, it tells me that it cannot connect to the database.

I'm guessing the problem is in my web.config file, but I am not sure... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `defaultProvider` attribute. It says which provider you are going to use by default.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" 
defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" 
name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

    <add connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection" applicationName="/" 
name="SqlRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this today!

Answer (score 0):

Do not configure two connectionStrings and two providers.
If you must, configure which one is the default provider.

Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step2

Comment: Okay I'll take out the one I don't need.